# How to Store Custom Claim types and values in Windows Azure Active Directory for Claims Based Authorization

Tags: azure, claims, azure-active-directory, adfs2.1

I want to store user specific claims data in Azure Active Directory to perform claims based authorization inside MVC web application.

Active Directory claim types to define:

Resource claim type

Action claim type

ResourceAction complex claim type

and claim type values I want to store for these are:

Resource - ControllerName

Action - ControllerActionName

ResourceAction - combination of Resource and Action values(hopefully as complex type)

and I want to store ResourceAction values in User/Group/Role AD objects.

Could someone help me on what's the solution for this and relevant resources with examples please.

I wants to avoid storing authorization specific data in database as I would be hitting the database for every request and is not flexible.

Many Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Azure AD right now, but I'm hoping they'll add this in the future.

Comment: You could use Azure Graph APIs to change values prior.